# Web Page Scroll To Right Side, Width Extending Infinitely

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Got a strange layout problem on my website. This only occurred on PC, but not on mobile devices, due to I have the "viewport" scale=1 set up.

I have disabled X scroll bar, so the x scroll bar's hidden.

However, when i put the mouse at the right edge of the page, press down, then scroll to right side, it will keep scrolling Infinitely.

[This](http://helperlove.com/) is the website.

Really appreciate for your help.

Comment: Remove the `overflow-x: hidden` property from the body. Notice how wide the horizontal scroll bar is... fix whatever is pushing your site width to that extreme and I guarantee that that will solve your other problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]the problem is you have put left: -999px; width: 999em; on most of :before element with position absolute and you did not define their relative try to remove all of them or define their relative your problem might be solved